# Advanced Calculus – (Real Analysis)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Def.  The statement that $S$ is a sequence means that $S$ is a function with domain some initial segment of the positive integers. (That is: the domain of $S$ is either the set of positive integers or the domain of $f$ is the set $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ for some positive integer $n$.)

Def.     The statement that the number, $p$, is a limit point of the number set, A, means that if $(a,b)$ is an open interval  containing $p$, (that is: $a<p<b$) then there is a number $q$ in $A$ such  that $a<q<b$, and $q≠p$.

Def. The statement that $T$ is a subsequence of the sequence $S$ means there is an increasing sequence, $i$, of positive integers such that $T=S_i $   .

Def. The image of a sequence, denoted $Im(S)$ for the image of sequence $S$, is the set of all numbers in the sequence

The question is:
        If $p$ is a limit point of $Im(S)$, then show there exists a subsequence $T$ with limit $p$.

**Here is my work**
[image]

My teacher says it is wrong that i need to show that $S_{n_k}$ is increasing as $S_n$ goes to $p$. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: I think what your teacher meant was that you didn't show $s_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $s_n$? It is missing in your construction of $s_{n_k}$, you just stated directly that $s_{n_k}$ is a subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the following notation: $S=\{x_{n}\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ for the sequence indeed.
If $p$ is a limit point of $Im(S)$, then $\forall \epsilon> 0$, there is some $N$ natural with $p-\epsilon<x_N<p+\epsilon$ and $x_N\neq p$. Let us take $\epsilon>0$, there's some $N_1$ with $x_{N_1}\in (p-\epsilon,p+\epsilon)$ and $x_{N_1}\neq p$. Now let $\epsilon_1=\min(\min_{j=1,2,\dots,N_1}{|x_j-p|},\frac{\epsilon}{2})$, there exist $N_2$ with $x_{N_2}\in (p-\epsilon_1,p+\epsilon_1)$ and $x_{N_2}\neq p$, and obviously $N_2>N_1$ by construction. Then take $\epsilon_2=\min(\min_{j=1,2,\dots,N_2}{|x_j-p|},\frac{\epsilon_1}{2})$, there's some $N_3\in\mathbb{N}$ for wich $x_{N_3}\in (p-\epsilon_2,p+\epsilon_2)$ and $x_{N_3}\neq p$, and obviously again $N_3>N_2$. Then we've found a sequence $\{x_{N_j}\}^{\infty}_{j=1}\subset S$, with $N_{j+1}>N_j, \forall \in \mathbb{N}$, with $x_{N_{j+1}}\in (p-\epsilon_j,p+\epsilon_j)$, and by construction $\epsilon_j\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2^j}$. So, we have a subsequence of $S$ with limit $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p$ is a limit point of our sequence $S$. Then for every $\epsilon$, $\exists q$ such that $p<q<p + \epsilon$  or $p - \epsilon<q<p$. Since $p \neq q$, we can choose $\epsilon_1$ such that $p<p+\epsilon_1<q$ or $q< p+\epsilon_1 < p$. Then we can choose $q_{1}$ in a similar fashion, and repeat to generate $q_{n}$, a subsequence convergent to p.

However, we haven't shown that this sequence is increasing (some of our $q_i$ may be earlier in our original sequence $S$ than $q_{i-1}$ ). To rectify this, we simply discard the terms in $q_n$ that don't satisfy this requirement. Since below any natural number there are only a finite number of naturals, and $q_n$ is infinite length, we are guaranteed that our resultant sequence will still be infinite after discarding terms that don't obey the order of $S$.